# R Huxtable position

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, huxtable

I'm using Huxtable for tables in markdown documents (printed in PDF)
My problem is that that when I knit the document, all my tables are in the end of the document not in the middle of the text.
Is there any way to use such thing as booktab = T in Huxtable package ?

```
cor %>%
select(var1) %>% 
tbl_summary(label=c(var1 ~ "Variable1")) %>%
modify_header(label~ "**Variable**") %>%
as_hux_table() %>%
set_caption("Title") %>%
add_footnote("Source ") %>%
add_footnote("Champ ") %>%
add_footnote("Lecture ") %>%
set_font_size(8) %>%
set_tb_borders()
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add your data ```cor```?

Comment: Check out `?latex_float`. It lets you specify the positioning strategy in TeX. "h!" might be the value to set.